# Eclipse : No such file or directory weird behavior

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt

There is a strange behavior happening in Eclipse. However, I am still new to this IDE and I really want to understand why this is happening:

This is the first tested directory:

[image]

This is my simple program:
[image]

I added the header files under **Project > Properties > C/C++ General > Paths and Symbols > Includes** with googletests and the inc folder and it worked correctly .

[image]

---

Now when moving my header file "Counter.h" in `src` and updating the path, it won't work anymore.

[image]

[image]

When building the project, I get this error below :

```
15:28:51 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project testGoogleTest ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
g++ "-IC:\\Users\\gaston\\Desktop\\unittests\\testGoogleTest\\src" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o "src\\Counter.o" "..\\src\\Counter.cpp" 
g++ "-IC:\\Users\\gaston\\Desktop\\unittests\\testGoogleTest\\src" "-includeC:\\Users\\gaston\\Desktop\\unittests\\testGoogleTest\\src\\Counter.h" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o "src\\Counter_Tests.o" "..\\src\\Counter_Tests.cpp" 
cc1plus: fatal error: C:\Users\gaston\Desktop\unittests\testGoogleTest\src\Counter.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

I tried to remove the path of src in the configuration, because I don't see why it's necessarry to do it here since it's in the same folder and `#include "Counter.h"` should normally be enough to make it work in this case but still failed.

This is so annoying and I really don't want to see this error in my project anymore, I also tried to refresh the folders with right clicking on Project -> Index -> Freshen All Files / Update with Modified Files and so on but still failed to build .

---

Edit :
Ok that's weird, now I renamed my Counter.h file to Counter1.h, the files updated their headers automatically and it worked but if I rename it to Counter.h again, it won't work XD
[image]

Comment: You have many different settings you show, which one corresponds to the build output you show?

Comment: The build output is when the 3 files are in the same folder ( src )